# Unable to use with url encoding in html5 mode angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, lite-server

I am using url encoding with angularjs to send data to a view it works perfectly fine but when I make html5 mode using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot GET /test/adddata/eayGcUzBmcW7XeLhgCCjA0oiQhmuJemjrArCKHPsffYKoVGTwZBIY80ejEfo50m9%7Cdata@domain.com
```

I am using ui router and the route is **/test/adddata/:data**.

**Note**: 
I am using lite-server for development purpose.

**Edit:**
when I tried

```
/#/test/adddata/eayGcUzBmcW7XeLhgCCjA0oiQhmuJemjrArCKHPsffYKoVGTwZBIY80ejEfo50m9%7Cdata@domain.com
```

in html5 mode it redirected me to

```
/test/adddata/eayGcUzBmcW7XeLhgCCjA0oiQhmuJemjrArCKHPsffYKoVGTwZBIY80ejEfo50m9%7Cdata@domain.com
```

and it is working but curious on why it works is it specific to lite-server

Comment: can you write the url you wanna access ?

Comment: localhost:3000/test/adddata/eayGcUzBmcW7XeLhgCCjA0oiQhmuJemjrArCKHPsffYKoVGTwZBIY80ejEfo50m9%7Cdata@domain.com

Comment: Where exactly do you receive this error?

Comment: when I try the url it says cannot get /test/adddata/encodedData

Comment: try it with # in the front  
`localhost:3000/#/test/adddata/eayGcUzBmcW7XeLhgCCjA0oiQhmuJemj‌​rArCKHPsffYKoVGTwZBI‌​Y80ejEfo50m9%7Cdata@‌​domain.com`